# How to put "extends" and "throws" statements in a method declaration in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm trying to write this as a method header:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, extends Applet {
```

Or in other words, I'm trying to have a method declaration with a throws and extends statement.

Is this (syntactically) possible?

Comment: A method doesn't extend. It's class or interface that can extend.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`extends` is not applicable for methods. Only `class` can extend another `class` (or) an `interface` can `extend` another `interface`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can't use `extend` on a method.  What you probably intended to say is, "this method overrides this parent class' method.  To do that, you just need to make sure you use the same method signature as the parent's and you also need to make sure that the parent's method is overridable.

A method is overridable if it doesn't contain the final keyword and if it's public or protected.  If the two classes are in the same package, you can also override the method if the method is package protected (it doesn't have public/private/protected on it).

You can prove to yourself that you're actually overriding the method by using `@Override` on the child method.  If you are not overriding the method for some reason, this will become a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend method. Only classes can be extended.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `extends` is used for classes, not methods.  You'll need something like

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet {
```

Also, there shouldn't be a `main` method in an `Applet`.